# how to dual boot arch with win 10?

Tags: arch-linux, windows, dual-boot

I was working on my arch linux for like two months and everything was fine until i had to install windows 10 to use some softwares, after installing windows 10 i couldn't enter my arch! there was no dual os menu at the starting time so right now i'm using windows 10 ! i can't just uninstall it because i installed it on an important partition i can't just format it to erase the windows , so right now i've got like 3 partitions : arch 100Gb ,swap 6Gb and windows + all my files 850+ Gb .. could someone help me ?!

Comment: Have you reviewed https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Dual-booting ?

Answer (score 0):

Windows setup is known to overwrite your MBR. In other words your GRUB2 bootloader is gone, so you need to restore it.

You can use [Super Grub2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) to do this easily.